# KeyFrame animation works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have an animation that slides in `li` elements at the side of an options panel.  In Chrome this works fine but it just doesnt animate in firefox.  I have setup both W3C CSS declarations as well as some `-moz` specific ones but to no avail

I have set up [a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4AUL9/1/) to demonstate

Comment: I don't see a thing happening but ok. The question is why is there only "@-webkit-keyframes" ? Where is "@-moz-keyframes", "@keyframes" ? You are targeting only webkit...

Comment: @drip jesus that was it!! I was too busy checking through CSS properties I completely overlooked that! Please post as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add prefixes for all browsers, not only webkit. :)

You are mising:

```
@-moz-keyframes //Firefox
@keyframes //MS
@-o-keyframes //Opera (not Opera Next)
```